# What does Redis mean by "taking full state of the expires existing in the dataset" - when it refers to expiring keys?

Tags: redis

What does redis mean by "they'll still take the full state of the expires existing in the dataset. Can someone explain what does this actually mean in more layman terms?

Below is the extract from how redis expires keys

https://redis.io/commands/expire/#how-redis-expires-keys

"However while the replicas connected to a master will not expire keys independently (but will wait for the DEL coming from the master), they'll still take the full state of the expires existing in the dataset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Means exactly what it says. The replica has replicated all of the `EXPIRE` / `EXPIREAT` / `SET .. EX` / etc. commands, so it *knows the expiration times of every key*; it just doesn't act on them directly unless it becomes the master. Instead, it waits until it hears that the master has expired a given key to delete it from its own dataset.